# FigVirtualFramebufferServer: Unsupported Operation

Tags: ios, arkit, wwdc

I'm trying ARKit and get a black screen with the following error message. The WWDC 2017 sample `PlacingObjects` is running on the same device without problems.

```
[] <<<< FigVirtualFramebufferServer >>>> FigVirtualFramebufferGetMaxCount: unsupported operation
[] <<<< FigVirtualFramebufferServer >>>> FigVirtualFramebufferGetFramebufs: unsupported operation
[] <<<< FigVirtualFramebufferInstallation >>>> FigInstallVirtualDisplay_block_invoke: FigVirtualFramebufferGetFramebufs failed (0 framebufs)
[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

What is missing?

Comment: Did you provide a privacy camera usage description in your info plist?

Comment: Yes there is a "Privacy - Camera Usage Description".

Comment: I have the same error in my own app not using ARKit, after creating CADisplayLink:
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkCallback:)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];  // here error message appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because of the setting "PrefersOpenGL" in info plist.

Comment: didn't work for me, do you know other necessary steps to solve this?

Comment: what is that setting?

Comment: I don't know which one, but it could be because of a setting. If you have any special settings, you could try changing them. That's what I did.